# How to scroll a particular element(see attached image) horizontally in robot framework?

Tags: python, robotframework

I am able to scroll window, but is there any way to scroll some specific element(like grid) present in window? The grid too has scroll bar similar to window as shown in image below

I found this solution.

```
Execute Javascript |  window.document.getElementById("your id goes here").scrollIntoView(true);
```

But unfortunately 'id' is not defined in my case for that particular element(grid) I want to scroll. Is there any other solution, I tried a lot, but no success yet.

[image]

HTML tag for scroll bar
[image]

Comment: Do you __have__ scroll to a specific (ID) point? Cant you just manually input the scroll coords until you are happy with the field of view? (Due to permissions I cant see your image, so I'm flying blind :D )

Comment: @Goralight No I don't have to scroll to specific ID point, I just want to scroll the grid horizontally(right most) as shown in image above(done it manually). Is there any way to handle this scenario in robot framework?

Comment: OK after looking on my phone, I know what you mean now. I'm not familiar with JS - but is there a `focus()` method you can use to focus something inside that grid? and then you can scroll within it?

Comment: I tried with Focus and then scrolling, but still scrolling is not happening there. Not sure whether this should work or not, I tried this...... Focus | xpath of element then Execute JavaScript | window.scrollTo(-900, 900)

Comment: And you can't use ID, Tag name, Class name or CSS selectors? There is no UID for this element ?

Comment: ID of the grid is not available. I can locate the grid using xpath only. Locating grid or element inside grid is fine because while the script runs, if I scroll manually then it click on specific element I want it to be clicked. But if I don't manually scroll the grid then scrolling don't happen and it didn't click on element inside the grid and I get error message like Element locator xpath.... did not match any elements

Comment: I am really struggling on how to go about this with nothing to work as a fixed point. I would recommend that you try and find something; anything, inside the gird which can be used as a fixed locator. With that use `Element.scrollIntoView()` as it saves you trying to nit pick a specific area. But I really don't know what else to suggest I'm afraid :( Sorry. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: Your solution works well for window scroll bar but does not work for grid scroll bar which is my requirement..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following one

`Execute JavaScript | window.document.getElementById('your element id').scrollLeft += 250`

(OR)

`Execute JavaScript | window.document.getElementsByClassName('your element class name')[0].scrollLeft += 250`

(OR)

`Execute JavaScript | document.getElementsByName('your element name ')[0].scrollLeft += 250`

(OR)

`Execute JavaScript | document.getElementsByTagName('your element tagname')[0].scrollLeft += 250`

(OR)
`Execute JavaScript | document.querySelector('your element CSS selector').scrollLeft += 250`

you can use any of the solution, not like Id or querySelector all other will give array of elements matches, so need to pass the index.

`querySelector` will give the first match element, so here not  required to give index.

`scrollIntoView()` -  Scrolls the specified element into the visible area of the browser window
`scrollLeft` -      Sets or returns the number of pixels an element's content is scrolled horizontally

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: ID is not defined for the particular grid(div) which contains scroll bar, so is there any other alternative?

Comment: Updated the answer, please check

Comment: I can use xpath only if I had to locate div(grid) which contains the scroll bar, by using class name to locate grid I am getting three result(as class name is not unique for grid). After scrolling I have to click on element present on grid on the right most part..

Comment: I have update HTML tag for div(which contain scroll bar) in my question

Comment: You can try using CSS for the same

Comment: Since there were other element with same class name, so I found out by increasing the index(replacing 0 with 2) in your provided code getElementsByClassName('class name')[2], it works for me. Execute JavaScript | window.document.getElementsByClassName('your element class name')[2].scrollLeft += 250

Comment: I am suggesting that use document.querySelector() where we can give CSS it is not className, more than index CSS is good, online will get xpath to CSS convertors, pass that CSS  and try